# Ajax It shows me only one pad in the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

I am integrating my site ajax to load content without reloading the page. Everything works fine but are of this style url http: // mysite / #.
I wish that were generated url to reload the page to remain in the same place, I could use also have a new URL for the likes of facebook. Any idea what could be wrong? I leave the code:

```
function nuevoAjax() {
    var xmlhttp = false;
    try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (E) {
            xmlhttp = false;
        }
    }
    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
function Cargar(url) {
    var center = document.getElementById('center');
    ajax = nuevoAjax();
    ajax.open("GET", url, true);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
            center.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        }
    }
    ajax.send(null);
}
```

And the button:

```
<a href="#" class="animabot" onclick="Cargar('<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>/text/text1.php');"><img src="<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>/image/road.jpg" width="60" height="34"/></a>
```

This is the div that loads dynamic content

```
<div class="center"></div>
```

**New EDIT:**

```
<sript src:"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $("#loadContent").on("click",function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr("href"),
                type: 'GET',
                data: {"anydata":"anydatavalue"},
                success : function(reponse){
                    $("#center").html(reponse);
                }
            }); 
        });

    </script>
```

The button:

```
<li><a href="<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>/bio.php" id="loadContent">BIO</a></li>
```

Comment: i can give you a solution but in jquery ajax. and its recommended to use that for all ajax purpose

Comment: Are not you could add something to my code javascript that would generate a URL?
Would it work the same? I have little idea about javascript, sorry.

Comment: its okk...its the same javascript or jquery.. but with jquery you will be easily able to use javascript. what you are trying to achieve can be done with java-script as well as jquery

Comment: Ok thaks, If the effect is the same as with Ajax not mind changing my js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a code to do the task that you want in **jquery ajax**

- include [jquery file](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js) in the head of your page like this

`<sript src:"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script`

assign a  `id` to your anchor tag

```
<a href="<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>/text/text1.php" class="animabot"  "><img src="<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>/image/road.jpg" id="loadContent" width="60" height="34"/></a>
```

Jquery Ajax bind with click event

```
<script>
        $("#loadContent").on("click",function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr("href"),
                type: 'GET',
                data: {"anydata":"anydatavalue"},
                success : function(reponse){
                    $("#center").html(reponse);
                }
            }); 
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with me, do not load the content

 <li><a href="<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>/bio.php" id="loadContent">PART 1</a></li>

Is that correct?

Comment: did you included the jquery file in your code.. that library is important for jquery to work

Comment: I have added and still does not work, do not know where you can be the fault